# Twilio PHP SDK - match sent message with received message

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have problem with Twilio PHP SDK. I lookig for solution to match sent message with received message.

How can I know response message is response for which my sent message, can I set some tag or something else to recognize this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no way within SMS to reply to a specific message. You can test this yourself by opening your own SMS application on your phone and responding to anything but the latest message from a contact.

So, the best way to track this is to assume that the last message you sent the user is the one they are responding to.

If you need to have multiple conversations with a single user at the same time then you have two options:

You can make the user include an identifier within the text of the message which you parse out of it. This is a bad idea because users will inevitably forget or get that wrong, leaving you at square 1.

Alternatively, you can purchase more than 1 Twilio number and carry out the conversations using different numbers. This partitions the conversation correctly, though may appear weird to a user to be receiving messages from many numbers.

Finally, you could restrict your system to only send one conversation at a time to the user.

Let me know if this helps at all.